# How to setup a workflow to be used with Infopath

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, infopath

How would I go about creating a workflow in SPD (to work also with a form in Infopath) that would allow me to make a selection from a drop down menu, prepare an email to be sent and CC additional email addresses that have been selected from a list box within infopath?

I'm quite new to this and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint workflow is designed for list item. So you could customize your list in Infopath form.

Make sure you have columns created for the list because sharepoint worfklow can only get infomation from colums